File open/save dialogue failure
Several months ago a very weird issue began on my Ubuntu 20.04 and still persists. I tried a lot of things to resolve it including OS upgrade to 24.04. Nothing helped - hence, I need in expert help, which will be greatly appreciated. Several apps (but not all) crash/freeze, when I call file open or/and save as dialogue inside them (e.g., by ctrl+o). Those apps include Okular, Texstudio, Wolfram Mathematica. I made backtracing by GDB - below I attach its output in the case of Okular. Intuitively, I guess that the issue is related to GTK, FileChooser, Qt, its libraries. But trivial reinstallations did not help. Don't hesitate to ask any details. I use Gnome v46 and X11. The issue is pertinent to only my main user. I.e., if I launch the mentioned apps through sudo, the issue does not arise.
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=signo@entry=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007ffff5a4526e in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#4  0x00007ffff5a288ff in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x00007ffff5ea5ffe in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff5ebae9c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff5ea5a49 in std::terminate() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff5ebb128 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007ffff6290236 in qBadAlloc() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff6294bf5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff644be23 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007ffff6455cc7 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007ffff6456fc6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007ffff64571c2 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007ffff6457517 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#16 0x00007ffff6457c45 in QSettings::QSettings(QSettings::Scope, QString const&, QString const&, QObject*) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#17 0x00007ffff739d57d in QFileDialogPrivate::restoreFromSettings() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#18 0x00007ffff739f61b in QFileDialogPrivate::init(QFileDialogArgs const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#19 0x00007ffff739fbe5 in QFileDialog::QFileDialog(QWidget*, QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#20 0x0000555555578b5a in ?? ()
#21 0x00007ffff6512dbf in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0x00007ffff7164f94 in QAction::triggered(bool) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#23 0x00007ffff7167eab in QAction::activate(QAction::ActionEvent) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#24 0x00007ffff7168acd in QAction::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#25 0x00007ffff716bd45 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#26 0x00007ffff64d8118 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#27 0x00007ffff6977b3c in QShortcutMap::dispatchEvent(QKeyEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#28 0x00007ffff69787b3 in QShortcutMap::tryShortcut(QKeyEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#29 0x00007ffff691b512 in QWindowSystemInterface::handleShortcutEvent(QWindow*, unsigned long, int, QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifier>, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, QString const&, bool, unsigned short) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#30 0x00007ffff69414d5 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processKeyEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::KeyEvent*) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#31 0x00007fffeb8821f9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so
#32 0x00007ffff6512e16 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#33 0x00007ffff7731001 in QDBusPendingCallWatcher::finished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#34 0x00007ffff6506343 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#35 0x00007ffff716bd45 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#36 0x00007ffff64d8118 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#37 0x00007ffff64db94b in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#38 0x00007ffff6535c0f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#39 0x00007ffff4b145b5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#40 0x00007ffff4b73717 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#41 0x00007ffff4b13a53 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#42 0x00007ffff6535279 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#43 0x00007ffff64d6a7b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#44 0x00007ffff64df3e8 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#45 0x0000555555569d1d in ?? ()
#46 0x00007ffff5a2a1ca in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x555555568800, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffd068)
    at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#47 0x00007ffff5a2a28b in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x555555568800, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd068, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffd058) at ../csu/libc-start.c:360
#48 0x000055555556ab65 in ?? ()


Okular, Texstudio, Wolfram Mathematica - All these are QT apps. I cannot say what is the issue, but it seems that there might be something wrong with your configuration. I cannot replicate these issues on my 24.04 installation. Please check if they exist on a live USB of 24.04, and if not, consider fresh installing 24.04

Could you start out with making very sure you have the correct versions of #38 0x00007ffff6535c0f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#39 0x00007ffff4b145b5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#40 0x00007ffff4b73717 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 those two libraries as compared to your dist release. Maybe do a reinstall of both of them.

So that would be qtcore and glib.

Today suddenly I solved the problem, which had made me happy. Thinking about Qt, I went into ~/.config directory on my machine and found there, that file "QtProject.conf" is in weird state: its size is about 1 Gb (!) and it's locked. And it was enough to just remove this file. Once it was renewed, operation restored to normal with the mentioned apps! Such a story.
